# Append folder name to file name and move file using DOS batch

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

There is folder structure like this:

```
rootfolder\subfolder1\file1.txt
rootfolder\subfolder1\fileA.txt
rootfolder\subfolderX\file2.txt
rootfolder\subfolderX\fileC.txt
```

Need to append the foldername to the filename and include current datetime. Then move the renamed file to the rootfolder i.e. like below:

```
rootfolder\subfolder1_file1_<datetime>.txt
rootfolder\subfolder1_fileA_<datetime>.txt
rootfolder\subfolderX_file2_<datetime>.txt
rootfolder\subfolderX_fileC_<datetime>.txt
```

Does anyone know script that can do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Stuff like this is the reason I love cygwin.  Once you go bash - you'll never go back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "datetime=%date:/=-%%time::=.%"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*"'
  ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('dir /b/a-d ".\%%a\*.txt" 2^>nul') DO (
  ECHO(move "%sourcedir%\%%a\%%d" "%sourcedir%\%%a_%%~nd_%datetime%%%~xd"
 )
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I've chosen to simply filter for `.txt` files - adjust the filemask to suit.

I don't know your date format or the date format you expect. You've not said whether you want the `current` date/time or the `file's` date/time to be inserted. `current` assumed.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Comment: Thanks it worked great. For current time I used SET "datetime=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"